# Save active class to cookies

Tags: jquery, class, cookies, save

Im looking for a solution to save the active class(`class="active"`) to a cookie.
How can i handle that? I wanna save the cookie per click.
So that every time the user change something on click it will save the cookie.
Here is my HTML Code. By the way i use JQuery.

```
<nav class="controls col_12 column">
    <div class="group" id="Filtersat">
        <div class="drop_down wf">
            <span class="spantext">Regionen</span>
            <ul class="region" style="display: none;">
                <li id="all" class="first" data-filter="all" data-dimension="regionenat">All</li>
                <li id="niederösterreich" data-filter="niederösterreich" data-dimension="regionenat">Niederösterreich</li>
                <li id="steiermark" data-filter="steiermark" data-dimension="regionenat" class="active">Steiermark</li>
                <li id="tirol" data-filter="tirol" data-dimension="regionenat">Tirol</li>
                <li id="vorarlberg" data-filter="vorarlberg" data-dimension="regionenat" class="active">Vorarlberg</li>
                <li id="wien" data-filter="wien" data-dimension="regionenat" class="last">Wien</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="drop_down wf">
            <span class="spantext">Leuchtentype</span>
            <ul class="leuchttype" style="display: none;">
                <li id="all2" class="first" data-filter="all" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat">All</li>
                <li id="singel" data-filter="singel" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat">singel</li>
                <li id="duo" data-filter="duo" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat" class="active">duo</li>
                <li id="grande" data-filter="grande" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat" class="active">grande</li>
                <li id="one" data-filter="one" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat" class="">one</li>
                <li id="tow" data-filter="tow" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat" class="">tow</li>
                <li id="three" data-filter="three" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat" class="">three</li>
                <li id="four" data-filter="four" data-dimension="leuchtentypeat" class="last">four</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

So i added id's to the `<li>`. So know i wana strote the li's with id and class in a cookie.
Somone know how?

Comment: Have a look at the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Comment: What do you want to do with cookie?

Comment: I want to store the class=active. So when the user come back to this site every li with active got active again. Do i need then id's for the li's?

Comment: But jquery.cookie works only IE9 & IE10. No better solution out there?